# Positioning menu in CSS

Tags: css, public, sharepoint-2013

I am having some issues with the CSS on this public Sharepoint 2013 website. The menu needs to be right on top of the header image, but in Firefox both pages layouts with only a title and page layouts with a title and an image place themselves next to the menu rather than below.

In IE and Chrome, only the page layouts that have headline but no header image mess up.

https://globalintranet-web.sharepoint.com/sandbox/Pages/Positive%20Impact/Environment.aspx

https://globalintranet-web.sharepoint.com/sandbox/Pages/News/News-from-Global-Gateways.aspx

Comment: you need to the menu placed on top right side is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.logo{float:left;}
```

and reduce the width of `ul.dropdown`

and don't forget to add clear:both after `ul.dropdown`

Answer (score 0):

```
.logo{float:left;}
```

put ul.dropdown in the given div

```
<div style="float:left" class="navication"> 
  your ul.dropdown
</div>
```

css

```
ul.dropdown
{
  float: left;
  position: absolute;  
}
```

reduce your ul.dropdown with